# Devise Database Migration - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails (4.2.1) Application that use Devise (3.5.1) for authenticate users, we are rebuilding this application in Rails (5.0.0) and we are using Devise (4.2.0). The problem happen when I copy the users table from the old application to the new application, then in the new application I can not login using the old data. In the devise.rb initialiser I'm using the same `secret_key` in both applications so not sure why I can not login into the new app using the old data, any ideas?

Comment: Any error message that can help us?

Comment: All I get when I try to login using an old email/password is the 'Invalid email or password.' message from devise.

Comment: Is your app in production or development only? Can you send reset token to every users?

Comment: I'm testing it on development first, yes I can send the reset_password_token to every user but I want that the users can login normally once the new app is released and without change the password

Comment: Have you checked to see if the password you enter is equal to the hashed password stored (you can do it) I'm betting it isn't.  My guess is devise has built in procedures to prevent this from happening.  Reset your user passwords and use devise to make them change it when they click on a link to sign in.

Comment: could you check the SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable to be equal in both versions?

Answer (score 2):

To start with, use `rails console` to ensure the issue is connected with passwords, and not the app - i.e. that `valid_password?` call of your user model will fail with proper password.

Devise uses [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d293e00ef5f431129108c1cbebe942b32e6ba616/lib/devise/encryptor.rb) method by default to generate password hashes:

```
def self.digest(klass, password)
  if klass.pepper.present?
    password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
  end
  ::BCrypt::Password.create(password, cost: klass.stretches).to_s
end
```

It uses `klass.pepper` to add to your password if present. klass here would be your model (e.g. user), which can be [configured](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-models) to use pepper:

> Besides :stretches, you can define :pepper, :encryptor,
>   :confirm_within, :remember_for, :timeout_in, :unlock_in among other
>   options.

`cost` is complexity of salt generation for new password storing, so should only influence new hashes generation, and wouldn't affect validation of previously generated passwords.

Devise uses this method to compare input password with stored hashed value:

```
   def self.compare(klass, hashed_password, password)
      return false if hashed_password.blank?
      bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(hashed_password)
      if klass.pepper.present?
        password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
      end
      password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, bcrypt.salt)
      Devise.secure_compare(password, hashed_password)
    end
```

Just debug it in your both app versions to see what input parameters in this method might be different, e.g. if you have different pepper defined for your model, `bcrypt.salt` is different in your two apps for the same hashed_value.

As to where salt is taken from existing stored hashed password, it's really [simple](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/master/lib/bcrypt/password.rb#L77). The stored string is simply split by `$` symbol:

```
# call-seq:
#   split_hash(raw_hash) -> version, cost, salt, hash
#
# Splits +h+ into version, cost, salt, and hash and returns them in that order.
def split_hash(h)
  _, v, c, mash = h.split('$')
  return v.to_str, c.to_i, h[0, 29].to_str, mash[-31, 31].to_str
end
```